I'm worried that people won't take my animation series seriously because of the fandom
I'm currently working on my own Indie animations series, Space Hazard, but don't know if anyone will take it seriously.
For the most part I was inspired by series like Murder Drones, Helluva Boss, The Amazing Digital Circus, etc. But my biggest inspiration was Rodamrix.
Having watched their series over and over, I wanted to make one of my own, considering I already had characters for it.
But my main worry is: Will people take this seriously even if it's an Among Us series?
I'm planning to have some drama, violence, language, and emotional scenes, but will that be enough? What if people just scroll past it anyways? What can I do to prevent that?
I want to catch people's attention, even if I do release a good pilot, what if no one watches it? I know that if I just make what I want, I'll find people who like it, people who are like me. I got into the Among Us community for the comics and animations, not so much for the game and memes. And I want to be a part of it, and maybe even inspire other people to make animations!
The amount of emotion and diversity Rodamrix was able to convey through a couple of different colored jelly beans was seriously impressive, but will be series just be another "Oh It's just another person using Rodamrix's style to make their own knock-off series." Even if I have my own style and plot?
I don't worry much about popularity, even when I get my hopes up (which I usually know not to.) I'm more worried about finding my kind of people. What If it's just labeled as a kids show so they ignore it?
What could I do to catch people's attention even if they don't look for the series? How can I ensure that people will recognize my work as something other than childish?

you                                                   you want
are                                                      to be
here                                                      here
 ↓                                                          ↓
beginner ... lots of failure and learning ... mastery ... fame
                         ↑
                     you want
                      to skip
                    all of this

You need to let go of the idea that your first work will be a masterwork and that it will become famous. Writing is a skill that requires many years, if not decades, of learning. Most writers publish their first novel in their thirties or forties, and on average writers write around 3 to 4 novels before their first novel gets published. I guess it is similar for screenplays or animations.
So what you need to do is write and create your work and then create the next one until you break through, and not worry about fame before you have even begun to write anything.

I appreciate your response, and while I do understand that it might not be perfect, or get a lot of attention immediately, I'm less focused on popularity, but I mean recognize as in, will people understand that it's not a kids show? I'm hoping to find people like me who enjoy the same things, Whether it's perfect or not. But I can't help but worry if this series will be enough to find those people.

@Feather Writing and publishing aren't usually employed as a method to make friends. You might find friends through writing, but if that is your main objective, there are easier ways for that.

It is more or so about making something to inspire people, making this, people finding it, and knowing that they shouldn't be afraid to make what they want without worrying about what other people think. And if I was specifically aiming to make friends, it would be through my writing and art, as someone with social anxiety, if you are suggesting more direct conversations, what you might call the easy way, is the difficult way to me.
